# NU1701, NU1202 package restore errors on fresh Windows/VS setup

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

Working in a team we have solution in Git that is being developed by 3 different devs. I went temporarily to different place with my laptop where I have fresh Win 10 Pro as well as VS 2019 Community (16.7.1). Having pulled out solution from team's Git I have a lot of NU1701 warnings and NU1202 errors. Other devs work with this very solution fine.

Target framework - .Net Core 3.1. Have installed dotnet core 3.0, 3.1.

Have read a lot of similar issues here, so tried to clean NuGet cache, deleting bin/obj folders, re-installed VS, installed VS 16.8 Preview along with 16.7.1 - no effect. The most confusing point is that the same solution builds fine on boxes of my colleagues but doesn't on mine.

Please advise what I can me missing in OS/VS setup?

[image]

Comment: hm.. weird. do you have the net core sdk installed?

Comment: yep.. 

C:\Users\TheYur>dotnet --list-sdks
3.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]3.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Comment: do you have the .NET core workload installed in VS ?

Comment: I have 'ASP.Net and web development' configured, since we develop net core web api. '.Net desktop' and '.Net Core cross-platform' I did not set up, should I?

Comment: I think you need both the .NET core cross platform workload and ASP.NET and web development one. The second one work only on the "traditional" frameworks (up to 4.8.x but excluding core), and if i'm right you need both workloads to work on web development with .NET core. I'll try and find some documentation for you

Comment: Just tried. Didn't help. And my co-developer does not have it in his setup..

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after couple more hours of try-and-fails, I got my solution built. Hard to say what exactly prevented VS to build before, but generally what I did is one more time to remove .vs, bin, obj from solution, some cache-like folders in %user%/AppData/local, added Windows features like .NET Framework 3.5, turned on 3.5 in Internet Inf Services/App Development Features, some Security settings like Basic Auth, Centralized SSL Certificate Support etc.